# Can UF4007 diodes rectify a 1 MHz triangle wave?

Tags: diodes, rectifier

[image]

If the input wave is a 1 MHz triangle wave, will [UF4007](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uf4007-d.pdf) diodes be able to rectify it without distorting the output triangle waveform too much?

Comment: Jessica, I edited your precious question as well. Please use standard engineering notation of MHz, not "MegaHertz".

Comment: Please check the reverse recovery time, trr, in the datasheet of UF4007 and compare that to the half-wave time of a 1 MHz signal. That, and/or simulate it.

Comment: Define "too much". Ignoring the potential distortion from imperfect diodes, if the input is centered around 0 V, the output will look much different than the input.

Comment: If the triangle wave is symetrical around 0V, the output will be a 2MHz triangle wave (with a little bit of dead time at 0V)

Comment: @kruemi, yes, will it be able to produce quite a good DC  traingular wave at the output in ur opinion?

Comment: How much is too much distortion for you? How good is a “quite good” DC triangular wave for you? Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: If the diode voltage is very small compared to the triangle voltage, distortions will be small. If  the triangle voltage is only a bit greater than the diode voltage , distortions will be big.

Comment: I'd suggest 1N4148 which is very widely available and lots of simulators have a model for it (I'm thinking of the Falstad circuit simulator in particular).

Comment: What source impedance? Amplitude? Is it truly floating? What load impedance? What distortion is permissible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97780/using-normal-diodes-to-rectify-high-frequency-waveforms?rq=1).

Depending on the Load value and "use", there should be a "little" difference between "fast" and "slow" devices.
Here is an example with 1N4148 and UF4007.

[image]

Used at 100 kHz.

[image]

Comparing 1N5819 and UF4007.
Note that a low load (50 Ω) should be used.
Current is 100 mA peak. Generator could do it.

[image]

Note also that UF4007 does "double" the frequency, but with a "negative" part ...

As asked by @SpehroPefhany and perhaps others, I add also the comparison between 1N4007 and UF4007.
Remember, however, that "recovery" time, EE&O, is defined with an important "variable"
which is ... \$ di/dt \$ ...  not "imposed" in these simulations.

[image]

Don't mix with this test, where a square wave generator is used (with a controlled slew rate).

[image]

Comment: Hi sir, the less load you use (high resistor), it will form a better triangle wave right? I am honestly surprised to see that UF 4007 behave more poorly than 1N4148 because UF is an ultra-fast diode :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have 1N5819 diode, is it better than 1N 4148 :)?

Comment: Yes, ultra-fast diode in the classic "frequency" it would be used (50 Hz). It is not a "fast recovery" diode.

Comment: Will try and add in answer for reference.

Comment: 1N4148 is a 4ns/4pF diode. The UF4007 is a 75ns/17pF diode. 

However, if you compare the UF4007 with a [1N4007](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/pdf/microcircuits/students/diode/1n4004-general.pdf) (more like 30us/15pF) the UF4007 is much faster.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  Should I add 1N4007 for reference?

Comment: @Antonio51 that would be amusing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, hi sir, so overall, 1N4148 is good to be used in radio circuitry ?

Comment: Yes, it's appropriate, which is why @Antonio51 included it. UF4007 is more of an off-line (off-mains) power supply snubber diode because it is high-voltage and okay for tens of kHz and hundreds of mA or more. At 1MHz+ you could also consider a small Schottky diode such as SMMSD301T1G which has less forward drop.